# Wicd Not Working

Tags: wireless, 13.04, wicd

I really don't like the default ubuntu network manager. I like it to have more details and stuff about the networks around me.

So i wanted to install Wicd Network Manager. But when i tried to install it on Ubuntu 13.04 with this link giving me instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD.

But when i installed it and everything it was asking me for a password for it to access my internet card..... but it wasn't my user account password and i couldn't get it to work at all. Can any of you help me in installing it or finding my password?

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure what information you want and thus not really sure WICD offers any more or less information then network manager.

I assume the password you need to enter would be the password for the wireless network / router and not your user name or password.

Comment: well.... i would like to have an active scanner and signal strength and security types all displayed in one place, just like WICD does it. i just really like the program. and no i can even start the program. when i run it it asks me to enter a password becasue WICD needs to access hardware stuff and what not... but im not shure what password to put in...

Comment: Network manager  does all that. At any rate, I have not seen wicd ask for a password to start, did you reboot ? If it is asking for a password, start it with gksu and enter your login password.

Comment: whats gksu? and yes ive rebooted and entered in my password but nothing happens.....

Comment: run it as root.